# Call `new` on a variable cast to a type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm writing some unit tests and I want to test that my constructor fails with invalid arguments at runtime.  If the constructor is called with invalid arguments in a TS project, it fails at compile time, so I first must cast it to `any`.

`my-class.ts`

```ts
export default class MyClass {
    constructor(public value: 1 | 2 | 3) {
        if (!this.value || 
            isNaN(this.value) || 
            this.value < 1 || this.value > 3 || 
            parseInt(this.value) !== this.value) {
            throw new Error(`Invalid value: '${this.value}'`);
        }
    }
}
```

`my-class.test.ts`

```ts
test('MyClass validates its constructor arguments', () => {
    expect(() => new (MyClass as any)()).toThrowErrorMatchingSnapshot();
    expect(() => new (MyClass as any)('abc')).toThrowErrorMatchingSnapshot();
    expect(() => new (MyClass as any)(null)).toThrowErrorMatchingSnapshot();
    // ...
});
```

I would like to clean this up so I only make one cast, by setting a local variable.

```ts
test('MyClass validates its constructor arguments', () => {
    // this type declaration isn't right
    const MC = MyClass as any as { new: (...args: any[]) => MyClass };

    expect(() => new MC()).toThrowErrorMatchingSnapshot();
    expect(() => new MC('abc')).toThrowErrorMatchingSnapshot();
    expect(() => new MC(null)).toThrowErrorMatchingSnapshot();
    // ...
});
```

I vaguely remember writing a generic that had an type parameter expecting a class, and I thought this was how I wrote it--an object with a function called `new`, but I now can't find where I found that on the web, and I don't even remember which project it was I wrote it in in the first place.

At any rate, with this code TypeScript yells at me:

> Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.ts(2351)

I also tried changing `{ new: ... }` to `{ constructor: ... }` with the same result.

I can leave `MC` as `any` which is fine for unit testing, but I'd like to know how to do this in the future.

Comment: try `const MC: FunctionConstructor = MyClass as any;` or even `const MC = MyClass as FunctionConstructor`.

Comment: Almost.  `FunctionConstructor` expects arguments of type `string` rather than `any`.  From *lib.es5.ts*: `new(...args: string[]): Function;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
test('MyClass validates its constructor arguments', () => {

    type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
    const MC = MyClass as Constructor<MyClass>;

    expect(() => new MC()).toThrowErrorMatchingSnapshot();
    expect(() => new MC('abc')).toThrowErrorMatchingSnapshot();
    expect(() => new MC(null)).toThrowErrorMatchingSnapshot();
    // ...
});
```

It's also possible to do this inline, though it seems clearer with the explanatory variable.

```
const MC = MyClass as new (...args: any[]) => MyClass;
```

Here are [both options in the playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1vWAewDsIAXAJwFdhi9SAKAB3ICMQBLYaANzBHIFMAXNACM0AD7QATOOgBmAJTpoAXwyqM+IsWgQ8AWz4AxcgQ4BeaLUVmAfOgxYcxePT7REhEhSo0APABU7CwI+AHdLADoosFIAcwghMAJ4AG0AXWs7fwBuBxxcT21YRGgLBGRIGEhoEPDaKIiY+MTk9My4JBQIXPzNEmg9YFFgsLhEKx6cPu1B6RHw4toAcjAmYCX5SexpgeBZUprRxYJyEBBNvKnCsYB9A-Ku6GqPLW9qUl8Hypstgq1dm7DQ4LcYXXrXQY3ObAsbLVbrMFXf6Q-bzWEnM4XVRAA).

Comment: You are allowed to declare a type inside a function?

Comment: Yes. We can declare a type inside a function.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was close.  The TypeScript authors chose a kind of weird syntax for this kind of declaration, but I can't honestly say I could come up with something better.

```ts
const MC = MyClass as any as new(...args[]: any[]) => MyClass;
```